# Phaser 3 load multiple single images from image file

Tags: phaser-framework

I am new to phaser and I am having hard time to find this, probably cause I don't know how to call it. I know you can very simply load image through url, give it name and then use it in a sprite.
But what if I want to load image, which contains lots of different tiled images and use each of them separately? I'd like to somehow define, that for example rectangle at (x,y), using (width, height) is an image, that I can then use in spritesheet. I found tilemap definition files, but they are usually one file per image.

I found createStaticLayer, where you can pass 2-dimensional array of numbers, where number is order of tile and that works pretty much similarly to how I'd like to use it, but it is for background only and I still can't extract single "image" for single sprite.

How do I do that? How is that called? I am sure it exists, I am just missing it :)

Comment: Try Texturepacker and follow this tutorial https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/tutorials/how-to-create-sprite-sheets-for-phaser3 The thing is that you'll nee to load your assets with `game.load.atlas(key, textureURL, atlasURL)`

Comment: For the second question please open an other thread or refere to this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/56310372/2107253